# Compile lighttpd in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c, visual-studio, cygwin, lighttpd

I have a platform independent source code that can run on Windows and UNIX platforms. To compile the source on Windows, there is support for cygwin. But I want to compile it with Visual Studio 2005. How will I do it? What are the project settings required to be done on Visual studio and what about linking options? Will I be able to get any idea from successfully compiled source on cygwin? BTW, source code is in C language. Please someone help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can give you more detail on this. I am trying to compile Lighttpd (a http server) on Windows with Visual studio. Is there any Visual Studio solution available for lighttpd? Currently it is possible to compile with cygwin, but i want to compile lighttpd with visual studio 2005. I googled around and found no solution available to compile lighttpd with visual studio. Is it possible to convert the project to compile it on Visual Studio? Anybody have answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you're out of luck. If this project depends on cygwin, you most probably can't compile it with reasonable effort in vs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically (for simple libraries) you should be fine by dumping all the .c and .h files into a visual studio project. 
Most of the time you can just drop it to your own sources. If you want to create a library choose create new project -> new library, put all the sourcefiles in there and the library will automatically be linked with your main program.

Comment: These files have lot of dependency on UNIX related API's. So I don't think it is straight forward to compile on VS. May be I have to replace all Api's with Win32. Based on that only I will be able to decide on libraries to be linked and header files to be added. I guess it is not that easy, may be impossible to do this way..